# Protecting private react components

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, code-splitting

I'm developing a single page application that consumes a laravel API, but I got a question. In SPA, until if I do private routes, the browser continues downloading component that is "protected" by the private route. So, I've been searching and I found the concept of code splitting and I thought, can I hide components that are private with code splitting? If not, can I do it in another way? Because, although I am protecting the data in API with JWT auth, I don't want to expose private areas, like admin panel, etc, even if it won't have the API data.

Comment: Yes, you can protect the code using code-splitting, as the bundle will only download when that route trigger, which you're supposed to prevent based on conditions.

Comment: I get it. But can i still search by browser for one component that is splitted being not authenticated, can't i?

Comment: No, you can't, that is the part of some bundle that has not downloaded yet. That's the whole idea of code splitting.

Comment: Even if i fake that i'm authenticated manipulating the bundle, it won't possible to load the protected component? (Sorry asking so many times, i want to sure that i did get it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to splitting code based on router and it will be download based on demand? If yes,

In react you can use React.lazy and Suspense

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: I suppose he's already gone through that, and just wanted to know if he could achieve the desired result using that.

Comment: Thanks Siraj for explaining more on question.